# Ionic 4 using components on multiple pages

Tags: ionic4

Starting from a clean ionic 4 project (using `ionic start --type=angular` and the template blank), I'm trying to create a custom angular component that can be used on multiple pages.

However if I use `ionic generate component` and try too use the generated component *test* in homepage.html by inserting `<app-test></app-test>`  I get the error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
```

'app-test' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-test' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs">docs will be your guide.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   'app-test' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-test' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs">docs will be your guide.

Here is what my files look like: app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

}
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>

  <app-test></app-test>
</ion-content>
```

[And the folder structure as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAw3g.png)

I have tried out several things by now and one work around I found is creating a src/app/shared.module.ts file and declaring and exporting the TestComponent there, and then importing the SharedModule in every page I want to use the component.

However I feel like this work around is not ideal, and there is something I am missing in how to do it cleaner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared module workaround is actually a good practice in angular and you should stick with that.

For reference: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules